# Авторизация пользователя через google аккаунт

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!
Я начинающий андроидчик помогите пожалуйста с одним вопросом.
Как сделать авторизацию в приложение через Google аккаунт?

Answer (score 2):

Смотри 'Google API' раздел 'autorization/authentication'.
Чтобы сделать авторизацию сначало нужно сгенерировать секретный токен, который генерируется по протоколу 'OAuth 2' (о том как он работает можете почитать отдельно). После чего использовать данный токен для авторизации.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Ваши слова учту. А знаете ли вы какой либо подробно описанный туториал? желательно на русском?

Answer (score 0):

Как начинающий, попробуй использовать [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin). Там все очень легко и доступно описано.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Очень помогли.

Comment: А какие недостатки у FireBase?